# PHP sessions passing values through offsets

Tags: php, session

I am working on the following code in file1

```
$_SESSION['manu']="hello";
$_SESSION[0]=$msg;
$_SESSION[1]=$msg1;
for($arr=0;$arr<sizeof($msg2);$arr++)
    $_SESSION[$arr+2]=$msg2[$arr];
$_SESSION[++$arr]=$msg3;
$_SESSION[++$arr]=$file_name;
```

In file 2

```
echo sizeof($_SESSION);
for($arr=0;$arr<sizeof($_SESSION);$arr++)
    echo $_SESSION[$arr];
echo $_SESSION['manu'];
```

However the sizeof session comes out to be 1 in file2 and all my session values stored in offset forms are lost?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of the elements in the `$_SESSION` array are subject to the same limitations as normal PHP variables: they cannot start with a number and must start with a letter or underscore.

So, using numbers as a session element is not allowed. That is why you lose them in the transition.
*(If you had error reporting turned on you would have gotten an error notice.)*

Rather than do:

```
$_SESSION[0] = $msg;
$_SESSION[1] = $msg1;
```

Try:

```
$_SESSION['msg'][0] = $msg;
$_SESSION['msg'][1] = $msg1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you put **session_start()** somewhere on top of your file? Add it in case there isn't one.

Comment: yes.. i did the problem lies somewhere else as it perfectly shows an enumerated session $_SESSION['manu'];

Comment: +1. You can not even imagine how many times have I done this :p